# Comparing dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Im trying to have a task that asserts two dictionaries defined as facts.

The following are two dictionaries in which the keys have the disk space that is available or required per hypervisor.

```
"available": {
    "hypervisor-01": 2321,
    "hypervisor-02": 46
}
"required": {
    "hypervisor-01": "200",
    "hypervisor-02": "75"
}
```

The previous facts assert should fail as hypervisor-02 requires more than what is available.

```
"available": {
    "hypervisor-01": 2321,
    "hypervisor-02": 46
}
"required": {
    "hypervisor-01": "200",
    "hypervisor-02": "5"
}
```

The previous dictionaries should pass as all the requirements are fulfilled. If at least one condition is not meet it should fail (there might be many hypervisors).

Answer (score 0):

Please see below playbook. I have added 2 more conditions that may not be applicable to your case (in case `available` or `required` don't have the same keys).

**playbook**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    available:
      hypervisor-01: 2321
      hypervisor-02: 46
      hypervisor-03: 462
    required:
      hypervisor-01: 200
      hypervisor-02: 75

  tasks:
  - assert:
      that:
      - required[item] is defined
      - available[item] > required[item]
    with_items: "{{ available.keys() | list }}"
```

**output:**

```
TASK [assert] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=hypervisor-01) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "hypervisor-01",
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}
failed: [localhost] (item=hypervisor-02) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "available[item] > required[item]",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": "hypervisor-02",
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
failed: [localhost] (item=hypervisor-03) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "required[item] is defined",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": "hypervisor-03",
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ka: "{{ available.keys()|list }}"
        kr: "{{ required.keys()|list }}"

    - assert:
        that: kr|difference(ka)|length == 0
        fail_msg: Required hypervisor not available.

    - assert:
        that: sum_max == sum_avail
        fail_msg: Required space not available.
      vars:
        va: "{{ kr|map('extract', available)|list }}"
        vr: "{{ kr|map('extract', required)|list }}"
        sum_max: "{{ vr|zip(va)|map('max')|sum }}"
        sum_avail: "{{ va|sum }}"
```